# Creating a house clip path like this one attached

Tags: css, image, clip-path

Is it possible to make a clip path that looks like this [image: House Image]

If so does anyone have any clip paths they can share with me?

Thank you

I have tried using https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ but it is not that great with shapes like this

Comment: you want a clip-path or the final result? because it can be done without clip-path

Comment: Not a fully answer, but when I was researching about css clips paths I found this tutorial on youtube, and looks like you can turn a svg shape into a css clip path which is pretty cool. https://youtu.be/pWYAzzfQP0w